# 'no rule to make target' erorr while building catkin package (ROS)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all, I am trying to use lua in a ros package named gazebo_test but not able to link lua library to package. While building package with catkin_make 'no rule to make target error' is occurring. I have searched for it, but nothing helped. As given in most answers I have checked for file in the path its there but still not able to build.

Follwing is my **CMakeLists.txt** file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(gazebo_test)

add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

set(LUA_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/include/lua5.2)
set(LUA_LIBRARY /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.2.so)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs gazebo_ros gazebo_msgs tf sensor_msgs image_transport cv_bridge)

find_package(gazebo REQUIRED)

catkin_package(DEPENDS roscpp gazebo_ros)

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} ${GAZEBO_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR})

link_directories(${GAZEBO_LIBRARY_DIRS}) add_executable(deepQ_test_script src/deepQ_test_script.cpp)

target_link_libraries (deepQ_test_script ${LUA_LIBRARY})
```

following ERROR is occuring

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.2.so', needed by '/home/sudhir/ros_ws/devel/lib/gazebo_test/deepQ_test_script'.
```

I have attempted following things already

- Checked properly that path of liblua5.2.so is correct and file is present there.
- I have tried to copy header files and .so files to package's include and libs directory and then updated paths in CMakeLists.txt using ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} but still same error.
- Added path of .so file to PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable

following were outputs of pkg-config commands

```
$ pkg-config --libs lua5.2
-llua5.2
$ pkg-config --cflags lua5.2
-I/usr/include/lua5.2
```

Still error is same. Please Help. Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272326/%27no-rule-to-make-target%27-erorr-while-building-catkin-package-(ros)/) by [sudhir](https://answers.ros.org/users/32150/sudhir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming your machine has a `FindLua.cmake` file, you are probably better off using `find_package` to find Lua, and then using the [Lua variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindLua.html) created for you.

For some reason, if you need to manually set the library path, you are likely better off adding `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` to your `link_directories` (it might already be there), and then `target_link_libraries(deepQ_test_script lua)`. CMake (and the gcc linker under the hood) will automatically search for libraries by prepending "lib" and appending ".so".

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sudhir](https://answers.ros.org/users/32150/sudhir/) on 2017-10-06**:
Thanks for replying. I tried to search for file FindLua.cmake on my system but it wasn't present. Also I added line `find_package(lua required)` to my CMakeLists.txt and `target_link_libraries(deepQ_test_script lua)` but it gave error of not finding FindLua.cmake in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH. Please Help.

**Comment by [sudhir](https://answers.ros.org/users/32150/sudhir/) on 2017-10-06**:
Very much thanks for your reply. I finally able to link lua. I used `find_package(Lua required)` and `target_link_libraries(deepQ_test_script lua5.2)` and it worked. Thank you so much.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-10-06**:
Glad to hear it worked!